# Converting string formatted date to as.Date dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy in r

Tags: r, date, format

still fairly new to r. I have searched through the forum on different solutions that don't work on the data set that i have and what output i'm trying to achieve.

I have a column containing dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy (WorkoutDay) and would like to format it to dd-mm-yyyy.

running as.date function through the column gives me this output:

```
## example date in on of the columns "20/03/2020"

rd$WokoutDay <- as.Date(rd$WorkoutDay)

##output  0031-03-20
```

I tried to run a format function through but I get this instead which is also not what I'm after.

```
rd$WorkoutDay <- as.Date(rd$WorkoutDay) %>%
  format("%d-%m-%y")

## output  20-03-31
```

I've read that maybe strptime or as.POSIXct might help but not sure how to use them

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `as.Date(rd$WorkoutDay, '%d/%m/%Y')` or `lubridate::dmy(rd$WorkoutDay)`

Comment: See Hadley's answer in the linked post for an "easier" way and Mike Wise's comment.